# Google Sheet "If" between two numbers is not working

Tags: google-sheets

Did I make a mistake in the code? Why is it not working? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B8SN.png)

Comment: next time share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/123729/